# create custom theme and labels text (custom tags) for my web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have web page where all the texts like browser title text, text for buttons,input field label text,heading text etc. the whole page can be customizable from Back-End. no value in the html page should be hard coded.

I have tried to achieve by saving data in indxedDb as key value pair, before loading page i ll get data from indxedDb for that particular page and replacing custom tag value with actual value. but there will be there will be 2 to 3 sec delay on that time page looks broken

```
<title class="custom-tag" >${home_browser_title}</title>

above is the browser title of the page

<div class="row pt-0 ">
   <div class="col-12 pl-3 heading">
     <h6 class="block-heading custom-tag">${pane_title}</h6>
   </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="">
      <table class="highlight">
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="custom-tag">${title_app}</th>
       <th class="custom-tag">${title_component}</th>
       <th class="custom-tag">${title_type}</th>
       <th class="custom-tag">${title_activity}</th>
       <th class="custom-tag">${title_time}</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody id="data_holder">
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

above is my html code and in js using custom-tag class i ll iterate and replace the custom tag value with actual value. is there any better solution this problem.

Comment: You could add hidden to the div and when your styles have been applied remove the hidden. This will give a 2-3 sec delay before the page is rendered but this should resolve your issue

Comment: i have actually did that and i works for tags inside body but problem is that i cant hide browser title text